# Why does iftex report incorrect package info when loaded via xy package?

Tags: incompatibility, xy-pic, bugs

I've encountered the following strange phenomenon.

First, the following test indicates that my system is running a recent (2020) version of the `iftex` package:

```
\listfiles
\RequirePackage{iftex}[2020/03/06]
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The log file contains the following:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 20.10) ...
entering extended mode
...
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2020-10-05> xparse <2020-03-03>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
...
 *File List*
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
...
```

Next, notice that calling `iftex` via the legacy `ifpdf` package does not do any harm:

```
\listfiles
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Here is the log output, showing that the `iftex` package loaded is the same one, from 2020:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 20.10) ...
entering extended mode
....
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2020-10-05> xparse <2020-03-03>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
...
 *File List*
   ifpdf.sty    2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
...
```

However, calling the `xy` package, which calls `ifpdf`, which in turn calls `iftex`, produces a strange result:

```
\listfiles
\RequirePackage{xy}
\RequirePackage{iftex}[2020/03/06]  % the iftex package is already loaded via xy
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Here is the logfile output:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 20.10) ...
entering extended mode
...
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2020-10-05> xparse <2020-03-03>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xypic\xy.sty"
...
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
Package: xy 2013/10/06 Xy-pic version 3.8.9
)

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 3, version
               `2020/03/06' of package iftex,
               but only version
               `2013/10/06 Xy-pic version 3.8.9'
               is available.

...
 *File List*
      xy.sty    2013/10/06 Xy-pic version 3.8.9
   ifpdf.sty    2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2013/10/06 Xy-pic version 3.8.9
...
```

On one hand, when the `xy` package loads `iftex` (via `ifpdf`), the logfile correctly reports loading the 2020/03/06 version of `iftex`.  But when we subsequently require the `iftex` package with that date, we get an warning that the version of `iftex` that has been loaded is called `2013/10/06 Xy-pic version 3.8.9` (which of course makes no sense).  And in the `*File List*` at the end (produced by `\listfiles`), we see the same erroneous `iftex.sty    2013/10/06 Xy-pic version 3.8.9`.

Somehow, the code in `xy.sty` has inadvertently tricked the system into assigning its own identifier to the last package loaded from within the `xy` package.  As far as I can tell, the relevant lines from within `xy.sty` are the following (lines 38--46), but I don't know what is causing the problem.

```
% Ensure that we are *really* running LaTeX2e...!
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

% So we can check for pdfTeX.
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}

% This file provides the current version of Xy-pic!
\edef\next{%
 \noexpand\ProvidesPackage{xy}[\xydate\space Xy-pic version \xyversion]}\next
```

How and why is `xy.sty` fooling the system into incorrectly assigning its own (`xy`'s) version identifier to the last package that it loads?  This seems to be a bug in `xy.sty`; can it be fixed?

Comment: no it is a bug in the latex package loading code (which should be resolved at the next update). See https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/408

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, I've now updated the packages and the bug is corrected.